# EMI filter in front of DC-DC convertor with resonance at cut-off frequency

Tags: emi-filtering

When reading app notes from TI AN-2162
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva489c/snva489c.pdf?ts=1674726033754

talking about the input EMI before DC-DC convertor, the filter is good, but I realized there was always a high resonance at cut-off frequency and I'm wording if this will cause problems for the design.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is:

1. why do we ignore this resonance? If there is a very small frequency component fall at this resonant frequency, it will be amplified significantly...
2. why should we design this kind of filter from convertor to DC power source as mentioned (from VB to VA) ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your point (2) has the circuit back-to-front. Plus in point (1) you haven't factored in resistance and real load current.

Comment: You should *not* ignore the resonance and always look at the output impedance of the filter driving your dc-dc converter. See my [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) to understand the interaction between the filter and the dc-dc converter. It is important to damp this resonance so that there is no overlap between the plots of \$Z_{out}\$ (the filter output impedance) and \$Z_{in}\$ (the dc-dc input impedance). An overlap means conditions for oscillations are potentially met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do we ignore this resonance? If there is a very small frequency component fall at this resonant frequency, it will be amplified significantly...

In general, we don't. But in your case there's something different: Note that the peak is around 70~80 kHz. Conducted EMI measurements are taken for 150 kHz - 30 MHz range *(This is for general consumer electronics. The frequency range might be different for military and space, I don't know.)*. So anything below 150 kHz can be ignored i.e. no need to worry about amplified 70-kHz-signals. As you can see from the measurement graph, there's no limit defined for frequencies below 150 kHz.

Plus, it's true that an LC filter has a resonant peak but real world imperfections of the electronic components (e.g. ESR - equivalent series resistance for inductor and capacitor) will come into play and bring some damping. So, depending on the selected components, the amount of peak may or may not be that high.

> why should we design this kind of filter from convertor to DC power source as mentioned (from VB to VA) ?

The conducted *emission* (or conducted EMI) is, simply, a measurement of how your equipment "pollutes" the supply line. So the filter is designed from right to left. It's like the exhaust filter in a car.

The conducted *immunity*, on the other hand, is a measurement of how your equipment is immune or prone to the disturbances caused by pollution on the supply line. In this case, the filter is designed from left to right. It's like an air-intake filter in a car.